# jQuery confirm (href) not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

I have a jQuery confirm action that doesn't open the right url. It opens the first url in the table row.

```
<td><a class="confirm" href="verwijderen.php?page=honden&id=<?php echo $rows['id'];?>" >Verwijder</a></td>
```

.

```
<script>
$(".confirm").confirm({
text: "Weet je het zeker?",
title: "Bevestig verwijderen",
confirm: function(button) {
    window.document.location = $(".confirm").attr("href");
},
cancel: function(button) {
    return false;
},
confirmButton: "Ja, dat weet ik zeker",
cancelButton: "Nee",
post: true
});
</script>
```

The problem is the jQuery confirm script only executes the first url in the list - in this case id=1. For all the other items in the table it executes id=1 also. When I hoover the url's in the table rows it shows the correct id's, like id=6. On execution of the script, it goes wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should resolve your issue:

```
$(".confirm").each(function(i,confirm) {
    $(confirm).confirm({
        text: "Weet je het zeker?",
        title: "Bevestig verwijderen",
        confirm: function(button) {
            window.document.location = $(confirm).attr("href");
        },
        cancel: function(button) {
            return false;
        },
        confirmButton: "Ja, dat weet ik zeker",
        cancelButton: "Nee",
        post: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Confirmed! Works like a charm.